# git pushing after adding user

Tags: git, push

What does this message mean? I can't push repository to git server.

```
user@PC:

~/gg/gitolite-admin$ git push
root@git.server's password: 
Counting objects: 15, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (11/11), done.
Writing objects: 100% (11/11), 1.81 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 11 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Use of uninitialized value in do "file" at hooks/update line 36.
remote: Null filename used at hooks/update line 36.
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/master
To root@git.server:/var/lib/gitolite/repositories/gitolite-admin
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (hook declined)
error: Fehler beim Versenden einiger Referenzen nach 'root@git.server:/var/lib/gitolite/repositories/gitolite-admin'
user@PC:~/gg/gitolite-admin$
```

Comment: What does `Fehler beim Versenden einiger Referenzen nach` mean?

Comment: @majidarif: That means something like "error during sending of references".

Comment: Maybe this will help you out: http://www.byte-artist.de/blog/2014/09/01/how-to-probleme-beim-push-in-ein-gitrepo

Comment: no, the tip from the link doesn't help. :-(

Comment: Looks like your push was rejected by the server, because it was configured so! [This thread](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy) shows how to enforce server side constraints with git. Perhaps you are violating them. p.s. folks: should this be an answer?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the hook `update` on the remote machine. Have a look at the script in `hooks/update` on the remote server and find the issue.